# How to use exported Environment variable in external configuration file in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

According to the docs provided by [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), we can use OS environment variables. Which is exported as `export VAR="some_value"`.

I want to use that environment variable inside the external configuration file (yaml file) for Spring project, specified using `spring.config.additional-location`.

I tried using that environment variable as `${VAR}` in yaml file. But I am not able to access it.

For example:
I have a environment variable as `MAIL="<my-mail-address>"`

My Yaml file looks something like this...

```yaml
app:
  dev_mail: ${MAIL}
```

For some reason, I want to access env variable in external yaml file rather than inside spring `application.yml` file.

Let me know if I am miss-understanding something here or you need more information about the question.

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Hi @thepaoloboi, I have edited question. Let me know if you were looking for some other details.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the application with the below-specified command. It should work.

```
java -jar <ApplictionJar> --SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION = <complete path to your yml file>
```

**Egg:**

```
java -jar testAppln.jar --SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION = /home/application.yml
```